# Why execv omit first argument?

Tags: python

**test.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $1
echo $2
```

Execution:

```
$ ./test.sh 1 2
1
2
```

**test.py:**

```
import os
os.execv("./test.sh", ["1", "2"])
```

Execution:

```
$ python test.py
2
```

You can see run `test.sh` could successfully print `1 2`, while if I use `python execv`, the first argument `1` was omit, why? What's the proper way to use this?

Comment: Hint: what does `echo $0` do?

Comment: You have `$0` set to `1` and `$1` set to `2`.  Use: `os.execv("./test.sh", ["./test.sh", "1", "2"])`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler YES, `Hint: what does echo $0 do` make me understand now, thanks.